# Simplify JavaScript Accordion

Tags: javascript, function, accordion

I have got a script which works really well for creating accordions. The only issue is I have to create extra sections all the time to add a new one. Is there any way that it can be simplified to minimise the extra work and script?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accord-one").click(function(){
        $(".accordoneContent").slideToggle("normal");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accord-two').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.accordtwoContent').slideToggle("normal");
         return false;
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accord-three').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.accordthreeContent').slideToggle("normal");
         return false;
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accord-four').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.accordfourContent').slideToggle("normal");
         return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just remove the "numbers"?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accord").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".accordContent").slideToggle("normal");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accord">button 1</div>
<div class="accordContent" style="display:none">content 1</div>
<div class="accord">button 2</div>
<div class="accordContent" style="display:none">content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your markup change all the accordion classes (accord-one, accord-two etc.) to just `accord` and then change all the content classes (accordoneContent, accordtwoContent etc.) to just `accord-content`.  Then you just need this code for them all to work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accord').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.accord-content').slideToggle("normal");
         return false;
    });
});
```

That will attach the click event handler to each accordion element and look for the relative content to toggle.

Comment: …and if there really is a need to differentiate between single accordions, set an identifier as a second class name or as an ID.